# A bash script for multi cloudformation stacks

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, unix, aws-cloudformation

Am writing a shell script (Beginner) which has to deploy multiple CF stacks in a particular order (Since there are exports which are dependent on other so the order) and need to parameterize $Stackname and $stack-type(Create/update/delete) here is what i could figure but is not working any help/modifications appreciated.
Should work like this below

`./script.sh -s3 -st update-stack -sn test` should execute

```
aws cloudformation update-stack test us-west-2-id-ca-su-s3 --template-body file://path-to-cfmn.yaml
```

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u
set -o pipefail
s3=false
iam=false
redshift=false
glue=false
lambda=false
alert=false
elasti_cache=false
step_function=false

while getopts ":s3:im:rs:gl:lm:al:ea:sf:sn:st" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    s3) s3=true
      ;;
    im) iam=true
      ;;
    rs) redshift=true
      ;;
    gl) glue=true
      ;;
    lm) lambda=true
      ;;
    al) alert=true
      ;;
    ea) elasti_cache=true
      ;;    
    sf) step_function=true
      ;;
    sn) stack_name="$OPTARG"
    echo "The value provided is $OPTARG"
      ;;
    st) stack_type="$OPTARG"
    echo "The value provided is $OPTARG"

    ?) usage
      ;;
  esac
done


if [ $s3 == true ]; then
    echo "Deploying s3 buckets"
    aws cloudformation $stack_type $stack-name cf-as-us-west-2-id-ca-su-s3-RawRefinedBucket --template-body file://path-to-cfmn.yaml
fi

if [ $iam == true ]; then
    echo "Deploying Policy and Role for Glue jobs"
    aws cloudformation $stack_type $stack-name cf-as-us-west-2-id-ca-su-IAM --template-body file://path-to-cfmn.yaml
fi

if [ $redshift == true ]; then
    echo "Deploying Redshift cluster"
    aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name cf-as-us-west-2-sg0304496-ca-su-Redshift --template-body file://path-to-cfmn.yaml
fi

if [ $glue == true ]; then
    echo "Deploying Glue jobs"
    aws cloudformation $stack_type $stack-name cf-as-us-west-2-id-ca-su-Glue --template-body file://path-to-cfmn.yaml
fi

if [ $lambda == true ]; then
    echo "Deploying Lambda function"
    aws cloudformation $stack_type $stack-name cf-as-us-west-2-id-ca-su-Lambda --template-body file://path-to-cfmn.yaml
```

This is failing to continue to deploy.

Comment: Not clear, please do add more information in your question and let us know then.

Comment: its like i have s3, IAM,Redshift etc multi stacks which needs to be deployed in the order 1 after next so s3:im:rs:gl:lm:al:ea:sf:sn:st options and aws cloudformation $stack_type $stack-name stackname and stack type to be parameterized depending on user input say ./script.sh -s3 -st update stack -sn test
aws cloudformation update-stack test us-west-2-id-ca-su-s3 --template-body file://path-to-cfmn.yaml...
Problem is it displays the help and doesn't actually reads next input/parameter.

Comment: @user2835563 Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this.

Comment: Please explain in more detail, what "This is failing to continue to deploy." means. What exactly happens if you run the command. What output and/or error do you get? Does your `getopts` support two-character  options?